# How can I delete my answer?

Tags: support

When I delete one of my answers there appears the question: vote to delete this post. 
Does that mean that others have to vote too for the question to be deleted?

If no others are involved I find naming it vote a bit confusing.

Shortly after deleting my answer I see it displayed with a hint:
Deleted by owner xxx seconds ago and I can undo my delete.

Do others see it too?

How long does it take to make the delete permanent, without undelete option (if it works that way)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Comment: @Ladybug How big is the probability to find above mentioned post, when someone searches for deleting ones own questions?

Comment: Who cares?

Comment: I care. I consciously ignored that question just by title, searched further, and finally found my problem here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It only takes your vote to delete your own post. Once you've deleted it, only 10k users and modes can see the post.

The wording might be a bit confusing, but it's probably like it is because 10k users can vote to undelete. 5 reopen votes from them and it is undeleted. The deletion is never permanent. You don't have final say (due to the licensing), hence it's a vote. Even if your vote is powerful enough to bring down your post.

Comment: There is no time limit for me for possible undeleting it ?

Comment: @bernd_k Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: This answer is only partially true.

Comment: @Ladybug What part isn't true?

Comment: @marc: follow the dupe link. He is not always allowed to delete his own post.

Comment: @Ladybug I never said a user can always delete his own post, only that he can undelete it. Or is that part wrong?