# Why can't we delete our own answers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

We can vote to mark our own posts for deletion, but we cannot delete them ourselves, a moderator or admin must do it. What rationale is there for this behavior? I can think of instances where the answer is useful in some way, has upvotes or comments, and deleting should be requested rather than committed. But, does it seem reasonable to allow users to delete their own posts under certain circumstances as well?

For example, consider [PHP Force Download Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083890/php-force-download-help).

1. The question was modified after I answered, and the new edit provided nearly the same code I suggested.
2. I answered at the same time as a few others, and the selected answer is nearly the same, but provides the little extra information that makes it more useful.

I noticed all this before the accepted answer was even accepted, and my answer was rendered moot, not exactly helpful, and (not really in this case, but potentially others) could be misleading. Also, I have no upvotes or comments.

In this case, doesn't it seem reasonable to allow me to just delete the answer and move on?

**EDIT**

So apparently, when I was deleting my post, it was being deleted, but this was not terribly obvious. First, the delete link asks "Vote to delete this post?" which makes it seem as though it may or may not be deleted, but you (as the owner) vote to delete it. Second, it still appears to you (as the owner) and any friends that have a reputation of 10k or higher, and not all of them realize that they can view deleted posts. In combination, it seems like the post was not deleted at all. Also, it is never actually being deleted, just hidden from <10k users.

As Benjol mentioned, perhaps the link text should be changed to 'hide' or 'supress' or something similar.

Comment: You can delete your answer, unless it is a rep thing I am missing. There is a delete link. You can't delete posts that have a certain amount of answers provided because there could be useful information in the answers despite the question.

Comment: In the question linked, I clicked `delete` on my answer only to get an information box stating I could "Vote" for the answer to be deleted, which I did. Checked back shortly thereafter, it was still there waiting for a moderator or admin or such. So, I clicked the `undelete` link to leave it around for an example. Why can't I be responsible for my own answers? Perhaps rep plays into this, but again, it is my own answer.

Comment: Good question. I can delete my own answers/posts but I have 9k of rep. Deleting posts/questions is not listed as a privilege: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: I have about 800 rep, barely enough to do anything. Oddly, I can delete my comments without approval.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73765/how-can-i-delete-my-answer

Comment: The **Subscriber Content** is under **[these terms](http://stackexchange.com/legal)** (para 3) which states that you allow your content to be licensed under **CC-by-SA** which has a [moral rights clause](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) stating that the author has the right "...to request removal of their name from the work when used in a derivative...". But again, you can only **request** for a removal and that too if the derivative use is derogatory. And SE allows you to request for deletion which is tied to moderator approval/votes/rep, does that satisfy the terms? IANAL

Comment: Related: [Why do I have to 'vote to delete' my own answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer)

Comment: Your answer at that link is deleted, and the note indicates it was deleted by owner.  It will still be visible to you, and 10k users, but no one else.

Comment: You can delete, and indeed ***have deleted*** your answer...

Comment: @Marc, [delete](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delete): from Latin *dēlēre* to **destroy, obliterate**

Comment: Re your edit: "Vote to delete" is indeed very misleading. Personally, I have more problems with "vote" than with "delete". It's already 2 years ago that Jeff [declined to edit that message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer/11359#11359). But maybe one should try again and convince him that updating the client-side javascript does justify the required code work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you saw an `undelete` link, chances are you were successful in deleting your answer. After you voted to delete, did the answer have a red background? If so, the answer really *was* deleted, but the system still allows you (and 10k+ users, if they happen on the containing question) to view it.

Comment: I believe the only time this wouldn't work is if the answer was accepted by the asker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7083921/revisions

Comment: @mmyers, if the post you're linking to was accepted, and then deleted (by its author), then [the FAQ might need a revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222): *"You can't delete your answer if it has been accepted.*"

Comment: @Arjan: I linked to the post mentioned in the question. steveo225 had indeed deleted and undeleted it several times.

Comment: This is misleading and confusing, because obviously if the system can show you your answer it didn't delete it as such, although it did hide it from public view. Asking you to "vote" to delete your own answer just adds to the confusion.

Comment: Also, logging out (or using another browser, or some incognito mode) will show the author that is has been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

I remember being surprised/troubled by this in the distant past. Not sure if I ever got as fast as mentioning it here (or on uservoice). (**update** found [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23802/incentives-to-prune-questions-and-answers): *"Another problem is that when you do delete your own answer, you can still see it, (...) How about collapsing deleted answers?"*

Why does it say 'vote'?

Come to that, why does it say 'delete'? For me, delete means gone for ever, disappeared, is no more<sup>1</sup>.

How about 'hide', 'withdraw', 'suppress, 'revoke' or 'retract'?

<sub>1. Think of the parrot</sub>

Comment: That perhaps is the problem. It said vote for delete, then it still showed up for me, and a friend (but the 10K rep explains that) so it appeared that it had not actually been deleted.

Comment: +1 for "Why does it say 'vote'". (See also my comment to the question; this has indeed [troubled people in the distant past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer/11359#11359).)

Comment: I think the reasoning behind "delete" instead of something like "hide" is so that newbies don't get confused with the wording. As they progress through the site and learn that 10k and mods can view deleted things, they already shouldn't be caring what it means.