# Why should I "VOTE" to delete one of my posts?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I have to 'vote to delete' my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer)

Why is it that when I click on the red circle to delete a comment I am asked, "Really delete this comment?" and when I click on the "delete" link to delete one of my questions I am asked, "Vote to delete this post?"
Shouldn't it be "Really delete this post?"?

Besides, does it make sense to "vote" to delete your own post?

Comment: Haha, this has bugged me for a while. [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102617/why-cant-we-delete-our-own-answers/102697#102697)