# Why prevent deleting own questions thus forcing the asker to possible more loss of rep?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, self-delete

I asked a question with genuine good intention but overlooked the possible endless debate and flame-warring issues (because I am not the kind of guy to get into them).

The question is getting several downvotes and loss of reputation points which I obviously do not want, but I cannot delete the question for 2 days.

I realise I can edit the question to avoid the downvotes (which I have tried to do) but it is now obviously not the same question as it was before and the comments and downvotes no longer reflect it anyway. So in my view, as the question is not salvageable, why force questions to remain for 2 days which the asker does not want to keep and thus subject them to unwanted downvoting?

In my view, if a question is closed as non-constructive, the asker should be able to delete it to avoid more downvotes and damage to reputation.

Is there no way to get a question deleted before 2 days?

Comment: It might be helpful if you add a link to said question.

Comment: @chuex: it's been deleted already (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253258/what-programming-language-is-really-to-blame-for-recent-java-security-issues)

Comment: There is no 2 day waiting period to my knowledge, so i guess you may aswell delete this question aswell..

Comment: @Dave: You have to wait 2 days before you can delete your own question once it's been closed.

Comment: He didn't mention that, but i think its 2 days so you know the reason why its closed.

Comment: @Dave But I'm sure people know why its closed if they want to delete their own question.

Comment: Clearly the community is quick to act on deleting questions which is good but I'd still prefer to delete own question. I do recall doing this before and so I'm wondering if this (the 2 day wait) is a fairly recent change?

Comment: But others can't see an example of a bad question if they are all deleted instantly.

Comment: The answer may be here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102617/why-cant-we-delete-our-own-answers#comment261759_102617

Comment: It seems the lost rep has been restored anyway once the question was deleted which allays my main concern that rep just keeps being lost while I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two days represent a "cooling off" period for everyone to get their bearings.

You'll get your lost reputation back if and when you delete the question after the two day window.

But the two days will give time for others to edit the question, or for YOU to do so.

If people are satisfied with the edit, the question can be re-opened by a vote of five members of the community, some of which will likely upvote it, and give it a fresh start.

Otherwise, the question will remain closed, an no one can answer. It's basically a no lose situation, because you can delete it in this event (after two days).